# range of numbers in BAT file

Tags: batch-file, range, token

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377335/batch-file-regular-expression) was created for me, and I've got 2 questions about it:
1. So if I want 2 unknown tokens, I need to write that?

```
filename??.txt
```

2. If the "or a certain range of numbers" in that topic is not cleared, I meant that I need to do such a command-

```
if exist filename[0-9].txt (
bla bla
bla bla
)
```

The [0-9] will tell the CMD that I need a range of numbers (that I will set) after the "filename".
But the ? is fine, I just wanna know if what I asked is possible.

Thanks :)

**Edit:** I've got an issue with that-

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,99) do if exist at%%i* (
set found=y
set num3=%%i
pause
goto forexit
)
:forexit
bla bla
bla bla
```

Somehow, the loop is being executed over and over again, more than 99 times as it should be. Infinite loop (I see the pause part every time).
What can cause it? Thanks.

**Edit 2:** Problem solved. Please leave this topic open.

Comment: #1: yes. #2: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377335/batch-file-regular-expression/7377360#7377360) in the previous question was quite clear on the issue, so I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist filename%%i.txt ...
```

Or if I understand your comment, you want to do an action if at least one of the file exists, which you can do as follows:

```
SET FOUND=
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist filename%%i.txt SET FOUND=Y
IF "%FOUND%" = "Y" ...
```

From comments

> How can I stop a for /l command (FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist filename%%i.txt ( + enter then + more commands + )) while it's run?

If I understand the question correctly, you want to process only the first matching file.  You can do something like:

```
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist "filename%%i.dat" (
echo filename%%i.dat
...
goto :MYLABEL
)

:MYLABEL
...
```

Comment: @ Juhana
Thanks.

@ Joe
I want to do this on a extended IF so I don't want it to repeat itself. Thanks anyway, it might be useful :)

Comment: It's not what I meant, but.. nice! That's great. I guess I'll use it. I've got one more alternative, but I think it's better than mine. One more question- how can I save the %%i into a variable? Just "set num=%%i" **in the extended IF** or something else? Thanks again.

Comment: @ETL the question is what do you want to do with %%i?

Comment: @ Mechaflash - I want to save it to the IF statement (in the **second** quote of Joe), so I'd do something with the file. Is `set num=%%i` OK for that?

Comment: Damn. I tried the command `FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist filename%%i.txt ...` and it gave me an error `%%i was unexpected at this time`. What could cause it

Comment: Oops.. my bad. I forgot that it should be with one % in the console.

Comment: @ETL After you put it into a variable, what do you want to do w/it? The reason that I ask is that depending on what you wish to accomplish, you may not need to extract %%i from the loop, but you can just iterate the commands in the loop which means you don't need to set %%i to a variable.

Comment: I see what you mean. BUT I need the %%i **outside from the FOR command**. Anyway, I guess I'm fine by now, if I'll have more questions I'll post here again. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: I've got one. How can I stop a `for /l` command (`FOR /L %%i in (0,1,9) do if exist filename%%i.txt (` + enter then + more commands + `)`) while it's run? Tried exit /b and no luck. Thanks.

Comment: @ Joe - You're awesomely right :) but.. after it will finish with the MYLABEL thing, shouldn't it go back to the for /l loop? (and it's not what I want). Thanks for the continuous help :)

Comment: @ETL on whether it will go back to the loop, if the MYLABEL routine ends with 'goto :eof' it will return to the loop, otherwise there is nothing that makes it jump back.

Comment: @ Richard A - Thanks. But I have an issue with that, please see my edit to the main post.

Comment: Oops.. my bad once again. Problem solved. Please leave this topic open until I'll tell you. Thanks again.

Comment: You can close that topic now.
I'll open a new one, about other questions. Thanks for everything :)