# Find files NOT matching *_abc.*

Tags: filter, wildcard, dos

In dos, when I wanted to get a list of files matching a specific filter, I could use something along the lines of:

- `*.*` - Means return everything
- `*.txt` - Means return all files with a `.txt` extension
- `*_abc.*` - Means return every file that ends with `_abc`

My question is, using that dos filter structure, how could I return all files **NOT matching** `*_abc.*` (In other words, return all files whos name does NOT end in `_abc`)?

I don't remember if this is possible and I need this since a company I'm working with is using a very old program that still uses that form of command filtering for selecting files for the program to work on - Also, unfortunately, I can't do it via a batch command... It has to be a single command line statement.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the results of your listing to FINDSTR with an appropriate regex search string and the `/V` option to filter out matching lines.

```
dir /b /a-d * | findstr /v /r "_abc\.[^.]*$"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution didn't work, but I'm afraid it has more to do with the program I'm using being THAT limited in its functionality. I'm going to mark your solution as the answer, though, because I'm sure that had my program been better equipped, your solution would have done what I wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer to a sort of unrelated question.  The answer does show though how to do a REGEX search on file names, and of course if you use a REGEX you can easily search for things that don't match the expression.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381962/1246574

Hope that helps.

*EDIT*

Sorry, didn't see you needed it to be a single line statement and not a batch.  I'll leave the above answer though in case it helps anyone else, and I'll also see if I can look up how to do it in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks for the post, regardless, @Jim... I appreciate your trying to help!!